# How can I add each element of fourier.getEnergy() into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

Trying to make a visualizer, the values in fft.getEnergy() (a p5.js sound library function) returns the amount of volume at each frequency. I would like to take the first 1024 of these volumes and store them in an array so I can map each number to a graph. The problem is when I try to add them to the array, the array stores only 1 value 1024 times and not the first 1024 different values.

This is a snapshot of the getEnergy() values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNUCn.jpg

And this is a snapshot of the array I'm trying to make while trying to push the first 1024 values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d2Pi.jpg which shows that it's printing one value 1024 times.

```
var arrays = []
    for(var i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {       

        arrays.push(energy)  //energy = fft.getEnergy("bass")
       
    }

  
   console.log(arrays)
```

Comment: Try  `arrays.push(fft.getEnergy(i)) `

Answer (score 1):

From what I read on this page https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.FFT/getEnergy

`getEnergy("bass")` return a "predefined frequency ranges" which I guess is an array of energies of predefined frequencies from `0` to `bass max limit`.

What you do in your `for` loop is pushing the result array of frequencies to your result array 1024 times (an not 1024 individual values as you want).

so what your are trying to do is

```
const resultArray = [];

for (let i=0; i<1024; i++) {
  resultArray.push(energy[i]);
}

console.log(resultArray);
```

(note that I don't use `var`. I Suggest that you look at the difference between `var | let | const` and that you learn about the notion of scope too.)

Yet this code above is not quite good either. I suggest you look at what the `Array` object in JS is and look at all the ways to manipulate it. Using the `slice` method would be better. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
const resultArray = energy.slice(1024);
```

And then to sort your array you can use the `sort` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

(Though be careful that "the default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings")

Comment: Thank you for your response Bastien! The slice function didn't work because getEnergy() is not an array, it just gives you the frequency in each frame (I may be wrong about this) but I am certain it's not an array, what I ended up doing was adding each frame to the fft.analyze() array then mapped it the way I wanted to, this worked out pretty well for me.

Comment: Well to be sure you can `console.log(typeof getEnergy("bass"))` and you should have your answer ;) Glad you find your answer in the end!

Comment: Used it, says number.